# What's wrong with my Racoon configuration?

Tags: debian, vpn, ipv6, tunneling, ipv4

I made the racoon configuration in [this topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfbuO.png)

And I set up the racoon of the left server and the right server.
Left server /etc/racoon/racoon.conf configuration:

```
remote 1001::2 {
    exchange_mode main,aggressive;
    proposal {
            encryption_algorithm 3des;
            hash_algorithm sha1;
            authentication_method pre_shared_key;
            dh_group 2;
    }
#        generate_policy off;
}
#
sainfo address 2001:123::/64[any] any address 2002:123::/64[any] any {
    pfs_group 2;
    encryption_algorithm 3des;
    authentication_algorithm hmac_md5;
    compression_algorithm deflate;
}
```

left servner /etc/racoon/psk.txt configuration:

```
1001::2         P@ssworD
```

Left server /etc/ipsec-tools.conf configuration:

```
 flush;
 spdflush;

## Some sample SPDs for use racoon
#
 spdadd 2001:123::/64 2002:123::/64 any -P out ipsec
    esp/tunnel/1001::1-1001::2/require;
#
 spdadd 2002:123::/64 2001:123::/64 any -P in ipsec
    esp/tunnel/1001::2-1001::1/require;
```

The right server also sets the IP address differently, and following error is displayed.

```
Feb 27 10:24:04 security-appliance racoon[13697]: ERROR: privsep_bind (Cannot assign requested address) = -1
Feb 27 10:24:04 security-appliance racoon[13697]: [2001:123::] ERROR: failed to bind to address 2001:123::[4500] (Cannot assign requested address).
Feb 27 10:55:52 security-appliance racoon[13697]: ERROR: privsep_bind (Cannot assign requested address) = -1
Feb 27 10:55:52 security-appliance racoon[13697]: [2001:123::] ERROR: failed to bind to address 2001:123::[500] (Cannot assign requested address).
Feb 27 10:55:52 security-appliance racoon[13697]: ERROR: privsep_bind (Cannot assign requested address) = -1
Feb 27 10:55:52 security-appliance racoon[13697]: [2001:123::] ERROR: failed to bind to address 2001:123::[4500] (Cannot assign requested address).
Feb 27 10:57:49 security-appliance racoon[13697]: ERROR: privsep_bind (Cannot assign requested address) = -1
Feb 27 10:57:49 security-appliance racoon[13697]: [2001:123::] ERROR: failed to bind to address 2001:123::[500] (Cannot assign requested address).
Feb 27 10:57:49 security-appliance racoon[13697]: ERROR: privsep_bind (Cannot assign requested address) = -1
Feb 27 10:57:49 security-appliance racoon[13697]: [2001:123::] ERROR: failed to bind to address 2001:123::[4500] (Cannot assign requested address).
```

How can I send an 2001:123::/64 computer's ICMP6 to 2002:123::/64 computer?

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 route in left server:

```
~# ip -6 route add 2002:123::/64 via 1001::2
```

IPv6 route in right server:

```
~# ip  -6 route add 2001:123::/64 via 1001::1
```